# Update site from core dev to stable

Tags: 7, drush, updating

Using advice from [Drush: Update core from stable to dev](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/drush-update-core-from-stable-to-dev) I ran `drush up drupal-7.x` in order to switch from 7.7 to 7.x-dev.

However I'm now in the position whereby I want to move the project back to 7.8, however I don't seem to be able to figure out how to do this. I've tried:

```
drush up drupal-7.8
```

Which produces:

```
 Name         Installed version  Proposed version  Status
 Drupal core  7.x-dev            7.x-dev           Specified version available
```

So it appears to understand I'm asking for a new version, but following this through just updates the site to the latest 7.x-dev.

Answer (score 2):

You could hack the includes/bootstrap.inc file
The very first line of code will be something like:

```
define('VERSION', '7.11-dev');
```

Set it to 7.7, and drush should accept that 7.8 is a never release.
I know that hacking core is strongly discouraged, but since the upgrade itself will remove the hack, I think it's more than ok.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to upgrade to a version of Drush that is at least [7.x-4.5](http://drupal.org/node/1247086) so that you don't run into [Specifying the version to update a module doesn't work in d7](http://drupal.org/node/1149284).

Comment: You can update `drush` easily  with `drush self-up` or something like that.

Comment: I thought I already was on 7.x-4.5, but i ran `drush self-update` anyway, and it offered me a bunch of options, one of which was 7.x-4.5, so I assume I wasn't on that version already. However after doing this, I still can't update to stable, and drush self-update continues to offer 7.x-4.5. `drush version` tells me I am at 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, it doesn't look like you can.  I think the basic reasoning is that dev is *generally* always going to be newer that the latest stable release and that would be a Drupal downgrade, which is not possible through Drush.

Basically, if you want to do it...you'll have to do it manually :(.

See [here](http://drupal.org/node/1323046).